# 16GB pen drive showing 2MB space after formatting on windows 7

Tags: partitioning, usb, usb-drive

I burned Ubuntu 14.04 image on 16GB pen drive on laptop having ubuntu.

Now when I inserted this pen drive it showed 2MB free space without recognising any other space.

I formatted pen drive on windows 7 PC.

Now after I rebooted my computer and tried to boot from pen drive, i was able to install ubuntu on my dekstop.

now my problem is that now also it is showing 2MB free space.

After using the disks utility I get the following displayed :

http://postimg.org/image/6pb8yzdxv/

How can I recover my 16 GB free space ??

Please Help !!

Comment: If you don't care about the data on it, I would just use gParted, delete all partitions (be sure to operate on the Stick, not your HDD!) and create one big partition that covers the whole 16GB available and format it in FAT32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove partition 1 and system Partition 2 ;

Then you can create a new 16GB partition and format it as you like

Don't you see that there is a 16GB free space unformatted at the end

Comment: Thank you ! :) .. finally I was able to format in FAT32 format ...

Comment: @RohitSharma welcome. don't forget to mark it as answer

Answer (score 43):

If you want, you can even fix that in windows, run cmd as administrator then type

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 1 (make sure its the right one)
clean (if it complains about permission, just type clean again)
```

then just make new volume in disk management, right click on computer -> manage ->disk management

Comment: Yes, it worked!

Comment: Should be accepted as an answer!

Comment: This helped - thank you.  You can create the partition and format it while still in diskpart: `create partition primary`, then `format`.

Comment: I did this in Windows 10, the disk stopped showing in my "This PC", though it shows in the Rufus software. Not sure if this answer still works.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to fix.  Merely open [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/), you may need to install it if it is not installed.  Then right click on the 2 Mb FAT partition and select Resize/Move.  You can expand that partition into the 15 Gb of Free Space.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to gparted.
2. Navigate to the pendrive. In my case it was /dev/sdb/
3. Delete all the partitions.
4. Create a new Partition which comprises of all the allocated space.
5. Click apply.